# Submenus with easy-menu

Tags: easy-menu

Can `easy-menu-define` defined sub-menus that can be activated with the mouse?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The documentation for `easy-menu-define` says:

> Alternatively, a menu item can be a list with the same format as MENU.
> This is a submenu.

So the answer to your question is, yes. This is possible.